# Show the keyboard and capture text from it

Tags: android

In my android app, Is there a way to show the keyboard and take input from it so that I can update a text view?

Usually the keyboard will show when you click on an EditText. However, in my case it is a text view and  I want the to show in it what the person is typing. But I am not sure how to enable "keyboard data capturing"

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you want to use a `EditText`?

Comment: Because I don't want the look and feel of edit text and I don't to show keyboard only when person click edittext

Answer (score 0):

Say your `TextView` is `txtView`, then you could:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInputFromWindow( txtView.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

This should display the keyboard. After that, you can handle `onKey()` callbacks in your Activity.

Comment: Cool. I will try it. But what's the point of the textview.getapplicationtoken in the above?